# getting an error Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'TransactionModel' while backup of box data in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to do backup of hive box data to a json file, so that I can use it for restoring data if data is lost,

I am calling a function with on pressed of text button to do this task.
but I am getting an error regarding converting failure.

```
Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'TransactionModel'
```

here are models

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class CategoryModel extends HiveObject
{
  @HiveField(0)
  String title;
  @HiveField(1)
  String iconurl;

  CategoryModel({required this.title, required this.iconurl});


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'title': title,
      'iconurl': iconurl,
    };
  }



    factory CategoryModel.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
      return CategoryModel(
          title: map['title'],
          iconurl: map['iconurl']);
          }

  }
```

and

```
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class TransactionModel extends HiveObject{
  @HiveField(0)
  String id;
  @HiveField(1)
  CategoryModel category;
  @HiveField(2)
  String paymentmode;
  @HiveField(3)
  bool isexpense;
  @HiveField(4)
  DateTime date;
  @HiveField(5)
  String note;
  @HiveField(6)
  double amount;

  TransactionModel(
      {
        this.amount = 0.00,
        required this.id,
        required this.category,
        required this.paymentmode,
        this.isexpense = true,
        required this.date,
        this.note = 'No Note'});



  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'category': category.toJson(),
      'paymentmode': paymentmode,
      'isexpense': isexpense,
      'date': date,
      'note':note,
      'amount':amount,
    };
  }



 

  factory TransactionModel.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return TransactionModel(
        id: map['id'],
        category: CategoryModel.fromjson(map['category']),
        paymentmode: map['paymentmode'],
        isexpense: map['isexpense'],
        date: map['date'],
      note: map['note'],
      amount:map['amount'],



    );
  }

}
```

Here is the function for creating backup file of hive box data

```
Future<void> _createBackupFile() async {
    
    File backupFile = File('${Directory.systemTemp.path}/logic.json');

    try {
      await backupFile.writeAsString(jsonEncode(Hive.box<TransactionModel>('ebook').values));
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error is :'+e.toString());
     
    }
  }
```

Comment: any Solution? this took my whole day...Looks like encode does not work as TransactionModel is nested...

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake...

it can not encode directly to some custom datatype like DateTime, so need to convert into map before encode...

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'category': category.toJson(),
      'paymentmode': paymentmode,
      'isexpense': isexpense,
      'date': date.toString(),//corrected from date to date.toString()
      'note':note,
      'amount':amount,
    };
  }
```